# How to merge all the objects in a nested array to one object by summing each property on mongo db?

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Given 1st block of code is the sample data and the second block is my desired output
What is the query needed to add the fields of **Machine Stats** in MongoDB So that my desired output is this (basically addition of all the fields in **machine stats** array)

```
{
    "date" : ISODate("2022-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "intervalName" : "Shift A",
    "operatorId" : "85875678",
    "__v" : 0,
    "clientId" : "ywegduywy",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-05T07:33:08.183Z"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "machineStats" : [ 
        {
            "idleTime" : 10,
            "breaks" : 10,
            "loading" : 10,
            "unloading" : 10,
            "runtime" : 11,
            "total" : 100,
            "activity" : {}
        }, 
        {
            "idleTime" : 10,
            "breaks" : 10,
            "loading" : 10,
            "unloading" : 10,
            "runtime" : 10,
            "total" : 100,
            "activity" : {}
        }
    ],
    "plantId" : "AACCS3034M-SEZ-01",
    "totalActivity" : 10,
    "totalAll" : 100,
    "totalBreaks" : 10,
    "totalIdleTime" : 10,
    "totalLoadUnload" : 10,
    "totalRuntime" : 10,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-05T07:33:30.213Z")
}
```

Desired output I Want (basically addition of all the fields in **machine stats** array except activities)

```
{
    "date" : ISODate("2022-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "intervalName" : "Shift A",
    "operatorId" : "495632582487",
    "__v" : 0,
    "clientId" : "AACCS3034M",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-05T07:33:08.183Z"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "machineStats" : [ 
        {
            "idleTime" : 20,
            "breaks" : 20,
            "loading" : 20,
            "unloading" :20,
            "runtime" : 21,
            "total" : 200,
            "activity" : {}
        }, 
       
    ],
    "plantId" : "AACCS3034M-SEZ-01",
    "totalActivity" : 10,
    "totalAll" : 100,
    "totalBreaks" : 10,
    "totalIdleTime" : 10,
    "totalLoadUnload" : 10,
    "totalRuntime" : 10,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-05T07:33:30.213Z")
}
```

Comment: That depends. You can $unwind and $group or you can just use $map. Why is the expected outcome "machineId" : "VIC-AUTO-0173", and not "VIC-AUTO-0172"? Is this arbitrary?

Comment: it does have the sense to have **machineid** in the desired output

Comment: Sorry that was just id of the machine that's need not to be added.. i have updated the question

Comment: @Alex Sorry that was just id of the machine that's need not to be added.. i have updated the question

Comment: What about the activity? What happens if one of them have an activity in it?

Comment: @nimrodserok Thanks for your response, No need for activity as it will be blank for most of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using `$reduce` to iterate over the array and add each item's data to the cumulative data, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      machineStats: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$machineStats",
          initialValue: {
            idleTime: 0,
            breaks: 0,
            loading: 0,
            unloading: 0,
            runtime: 0,
            total: 0
          },
          in: {
            idleTime: {$add: ["$$value.idleTime", "$$this.idleTime"]},
            breaks: {$add: ["$$value.breaks", "$$this.breaks"]},
            loading: {$add: ["$$value.loading", "$$this.loading"]},
            unloading: {$add: ["$$value.unloading", "$$this.unloading"]},
            total: {$add: ["$$value.total", "$$this.total"]},
            runtime: {$add: ["$$value.runtime", "$$this.runtime"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oaG8aSOl4Zl).

Another option is to use `$unwind` and `$group` but it should be less efficient for this specific requested output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **map** and **reduce** methods to complete this kind of calculation in a mongo query.

- **Reduce**: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/
- **Map**: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/